# Can non-box user upload a document to box folder using shared link?

Tags: java, box

Non-box account holder want to upload a document to box account using folder's shared link.

Box user share a folder's path with non-box user.Non-box user want to upload a

document to that folder using shared folder's link.

Is this possible in box? or Is there any other way to upload to box's folder?

Answer (score 0):

Using shared link , non-box user cannot upload documents to box.But non-box user can upload files to box folder using "file upload using email" option.

This options is can be enabled by following steps.
Go to box.com ->click down arrow right to folder ->upload options->Email files to this folder->check the box "Allow uploads to this folder via email" -> copy the email id-> save.

Finally send file as a attachment to that email id .The file will be uploaded and you will receive a confirmation mail.